# ¿Por qué en Javascript no puedo usar una variable para obtener un valor en Map?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código en Javascript que escucha los cambios en un `select` según la opción seleccionada debería sacar el valor que tenga ese número en un `Map`.

Lo que hago es guardar el valor del `option` seleccionado en la variable `selValue` y luego intento usar esa variable para obtener el valor de esa llave en el mapa. Cuando hago eso obtengo `undefined`, sin embargo cuando uso un número directamente sí funciona.

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe ese comportamiento?

¿Cómo podría usar la variable para obtener el valor de esa llave en el mapa, de modo que el código sea dinámico?

**NOTA:** Sé que se podría hacer de otra forma, pero quisiera hacerlo con un `Map` o al menos saber a qué se debe este comportamiento.

Aquí está lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set(1, "action for option 1");
map.set(2, "action for option 2");
map.set(3, "action for option 3");

selTest.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var selValue = this.value;
  console.log(selValue);
  var thisAction = map.get(selValue); //No funciona
  console.log(thisAction);
  console.log(map.get(1)); //Funciona, pero no es dinámico
});
```

```html
<select id="selTest">
  <option value="-1">-seleccione-</option>
  <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las claves Map son comparadas estrictamente (valor y tipo), tu `this.value` es un string en vez de un number, si pruebas `+this.value` funcionará.

Según dice [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map):

#### Igualdad de claves

> La igualdad de claves esta basada en el algoritmo "SameValueZero": NaN es considerado lo mismo que NaN (sin importar que NaN !== NaN) y todos los otros operadores son considerados iguales de acuerdo a la semantica del operador ===. En las primeras versiones de ECMAScript 6 -0 y +0 eran considarados distintos (even though -0 === +0), esto fue cambiado en posteriores versiones y ha sido implementado en Gecko 29 (Firefox 29 / Thunderbird 29 / SeaMonkey 2.26) (error 952870) and a recent nightly Chrome.

Comment: Lo ignoraba totalmente, he usado `+this.value` como dices y ha funcionado. Gracias por tu respuesta.